# Access @section defined in view from partial

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page with a tab, each tab content is placed as a `partial view with some scripts`

As a best practice, I want to add all the scripts in the bottom of the page. Since the partial views are unable to access the `@section` i placed all the scripts in page itself, it is hard to read.

Tabs are loaded based on permission. Even though user doesnt have permission, still i render those scripts.

How can i `add all the scripts referred in page/partial view at the bottom`?

***WebForm Context:*** I think it is similar to accessing the content place holder from a user control

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by writting this with some `Extension Method` with the MVCHtmlHelper

Here is the code

```
private const string SCRIPTBLOCK_BUILDER = "ScriptBlockBuilder";

public static MvcHtmlString ScriptBlock(this WebViewPage webPage,
Func<dynamic, HelperResult> template)
{
if (!webPage.IsAjax)
{
var scriptBuilder = webPage.Context.Items[SCRIPTBLOCK_BUILDER]
as StringBuilder ?? new StringBuilder();

scriptBuilder.Append(template(null).ToHtmlString());

webPage.Context.Items[SCRIPTBLOCK_BUILDER] = scriptBuilder;

return new MvcHtmlString(string.Empty);
}
return new MvcHtmlString(template(null).ToHtmlString());
}

public static MvcHtmlString WriteScriptBlocks(this WebViewPage webPage)
{
var scriptBuilder = webPage.Context.Items[SCRIPTBLOCK_BUILDER]
as StringBuilder ?? new StringBuilder();

return new MvcHtmlString(scriptBuilder.ToString());
}
```

In your layout design

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", false)
@this.WriteScriptBlocks()
```

In Partial View

```
@model ViewModel


@this.ScriptBlock(
@<script  type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        notify('@message', '@Model.Type.ToString()', '@Model.Type.ToString().ToLower()');
    });
</script>)
```

Refer this [post](http://blog.logrythmik.com/post/A-Script-Block-Templated-Delegate-for-Inline-Scripts-in-Razor-Partials.aspx)